# Foreign key refering non primary-key column on parent table

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

Let's say we have 2 tables `Parent(col1, col2, col3)` and `Child(col4, col5, col6)`. What is the requirement on Parent's columns to have a `FOREIGN KEY (col4, col5) REFERENCES Parent(col1, col2)` ?

I remember reading that a PRIMARY KEY on (col1, col2) is not required. In [SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx) the only requirement is that (col1, col2) has a unique constraint on it. How about Oracle ?

Comment: Try and see. (Should have known by now.)

Comment: Or look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52199); the first sentence describes "a relationship between that foreign key and a specified primary or unique key". (I believe that's part of the SQL standard)